# Apache airflow celery workers on localhost

Tags: celery, airflow

How many apache airflow celery workers can I start on localhost? I guess the default setting should be one celery worker that work concurrently by multi-threading. The concurrency can be set in airflow.cfg file (default is 16).

I checked the flower server and there is only one celery worker.

Is it possible to add another celery worker to my localhost?

Comment: I believe there's no limit imposed by `Airflow` in this regard. Celery might cap the number of workers on a machine, but even that seems a remote possibility. You need to play around with 1. Celery (more likely) 2. Airflow configs, and I think this can be pulled off

Comment: @y2k-shubham. I also thought there's no limit, but how to run a second celery worker on localhsot, that would be my question. I don't think the configure file has something related, may be I will check source code.

Comment: Oh that? Did you check `puckel/docker-airflow`?

Comment: I deploy my airflow and celery on my Ubuntu localhost, not using docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can actually start as many celery workers with cmd

airflow worker -cn [hostname]